# coverage.xml is not being generated despite all tests are passing

Tags: python, python-unittest, coverage.py

I have been trying from long time to generate coverage for the tests i have written.
First i tried the simple command :-

```
coverage run pythontestfilename.py
coverage xml -o coverage.xml
```

This generated the coverage.xml in the current directory. But coverage all took into consideration environment files. So i tried with omit command but no coverage file was generated then i moved to config file and i am still facing the same issue.
here is my config file .coveragerc and the command

```
coverage run --rcfile=$BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY/.coveragerc $BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY/testfilename.py

[run]
omit =
     /env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*

[html]
directory = ./coverage.html

[xml]
output = ./coverage.xml
```

This is my first time working on python and also this build is running on VSTS. I searched a lot but there is no solution for the given problem. can anyone please point to me in the right direction?

Comment: Usually the best thing is `[run] source = .`

Comment: @NedBatchelder Yes I resolved it doing same. Thanks!